# Controlling du ordering

Tags: shell, du

Short version; how can I control the order in which `du` scans directories?

**NOTE:** Sorting afterwards is not sufficient, I need to change the order that `du` scans, not the ordering of the results.

For a bit of background; I have a simple rsync-based backup with a bunch of snapshots in a directory, all named by the date/time they were created.

So a sample might look like this:

```
2019-08
2019-09
2019-09-20
2019-09-21
2019-09-23-161447
2019-09-23-172658
```

i.e- I've got hourlies (at the end), collapsed into dailies (middle) and then eventually into monthlies (top), which works great since these work well with the natural sorting of `ls`.

The problem however, is that when I run `du .` the ordering is unpredictable, or at least, it's not the same (oldest to newest) so the results aren't useful as I'd like; sometimes I'll get a daily or even hourly being scanned ahead of the monthlies, and the ordering only sometimes matches the one I want.

What I want, ideally, is for `du` to always evaluate the snapshots from oldest to newest, as this way `du` will give the sizes for all later snapshots as the a size difference/delta (since unchanged files are hard-linked, it only counts the changes for later snapshots).

Is it possible to force a natural sort order for the order in which `du` scans directories?

Comment: Without knowing if you were letting `du`  recurse on its own, vs being given a list of specific directories on the command line, I don't know how anyone but you could have answered this. Certainly the question *implied* that it was `du`, not the calling shell, that determined the ordering you wanted to change. (If you'd shown the command-line usage at hand, that would have provided sufficient clarity to override that implication).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I specifically stated use of `du .` (i.e- `du` current directory) in my question.

Comment: Ahh. Then the answer is "no", or rather, "read the source to your specific implementation" (as `du` is not a POSIX-standardized tool, there's no common specification to which implementations are held).

Comment: ...generally speaking, anything where ordering is undefined is just using the `readdir()` syscall, and relying on your operating system feeding things back in whichever order your filesystem happens to use -- which is generally an implementation detail of that specific filesystem, and will vary on how directory entries are hashed/ordered/etc.

Comment: "How does GNU du v1.2.3 sort directories when recursing on its own?" would, at least, be specific enough to be an answerable question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason it hadn't occurred to me that if I just pass all the snapshots as arguments, then `du` would still ignore additional hard-links, so a possible answer in my case is to do something like:

`du -sh /path/to/snapshots/*-*`

Since my parent directory contains no other entries with hyphens, this expands to every single snapshot within it, and seems to be given in a natural sort order. Depending how similar your own use-case is you may need to adjust the pattern, or obtain the list some other way.

Before I mark this answer as correct though, can I please have someone confirm; is this a reliable way to order the snapshots? It seems to give me a natural sort order, but I haven't been able to find a source confirming if this will always be the case. If it isn't reliable, or even if it is, are there any other/more flexible alternatives?

Comment: Glob ordering is well-defined if your collation order (`LC_COLLATE`) is known.